# Continuity Camera for macOS and iOS

Tags: ios, camera, macos-mojave, continuity

In macOS Mojave the continuity camera was introduced. Letting the user take pictures on the iPhone or iPad right into an application on the mac such as Notes, Messages, Keynote, Mail and TextEdit.

Is this functionality available for third party developers.

> https://www.apple.com/macos/mojave/
>
> #### Continuity Camera
>
> Take a photo right to your Mac. Now you can use your
>   iPhone to shoot or scan a nearby object or document and have it
>   automatically appear on your Mac. Just choose Insert a Photo from the
>   File menu. You can take a photo of something on your desk and
>   instantly see it in your Pages document. Or scan a receipt, and a
>   straightened version is immediately available in the Finder as a PDF.
>   Continuity Camera works in the Finder, Mail, Messages, Notes, Pages,
>   Keynote, and Numbers. It’s another way iPhone and Mac just click.

[image: Continuity Camera]

Comment: As of macOS 13 this is fairly easy. See the [Supporting Continuity Camera in your macOS app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/supporting_continuity_camera_in_your_macos_app) sample app provided by Apple.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`validRequestorForSendType:returnType:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428379-validrequestorforsendtype?language=objc#). More info in WWDC 2018 [Session 209](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/209/) around minute 36.

Answer (score 2):

Thomas Zoechling wrote a [little sample project](https://thomas.zoechling.me/journal/2018/10/Continuity.html) that you can use to get continuity scanning working — it's pretty touchy and VERY inflexible. (Eg, there's no way to just directly invoke the Continuity Camera from your own code, you HAVE to use an NSMenu!)